# How to fill combobox with country names in a C# windows application

Tags: c#, combobox

I tried following code to fill combobox with country names

```
private void PopulateCountryComboBox()
{
            RegionInfo country = new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("en-US", false).LCID);
            List countryNames = new List();
            foreach (CultureInfo cul in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
            {
                country = new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo(cul.Name, false).LCID);
                countryNames.Add(country.DisplayName.ToString());
            }

            IEnumerable nameAdded = countryNames.OrderBy(names => names).Distinct();

            foreach (string item in nameAdded)
            {
                cmbcountry.Items.Add(item);

            }
}
```

I am getting following error

> Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: Debug he function and then you can easily identify which line of code throws the exception,check my answer it may solve your issue

Answer (score 4):

`List<T>` is a generic collection. You need to supply what type it's going to be a list of.

Try:

```
List<string> countryNames = new List<string>();
```

Comment: @user3378112: Glad it helped! If it answers the question, can you mark  is the accepted answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
  RegionInfo country = new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("en-US", false).LCID);
  List countryNames = new List();
```

as

```
RegionInfo country = new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("en-US", false).LCID);
  List<string> countryNames = new List<string>();
```

this may solve your issue